# Use "include stdafx.h" when teaching C++ to children?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm teaching high school students programming in C++ this summer. I have to teach them material in a week's time. Reading through the tutorial the company gave me, they suggest that I use "include stdafx.h" in the programs right at the get-go.

So do you think

```
include stdafx.h
```

is necessary when teaching the basics of programming to kids? If so, why?

Thanks!

Comment: Not at all. Precompiled headers have no place in small learning examples. The odds are that there will be several occasions where people get into trouble when they don't uncheck that option, though, so it might be worth at least mentioning a bit, but making sure they know it isn't important to learn (yet).

Comment: So I can just omit it? Like just have #include <iostream> ... and all that jazz to teach them first? And would it be worth it to point this out to the people who created the curriculum?

Comment: Even i used visual studio after long time and confused with the compiler error that did you include stdafx.h

Comment: Furthermore, Microsoft specific cruft of any type has no place in learning C++, the language. Moreover, "AFX" stands for Application Frameworx; an ancient name for MFC. The name makes no sense even in Windows-specific code that is not based on the MFC library.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much, guys, you rock! So how should I start off with them creating a new project? Check "Create directory," and empty project?

Comment: @Kaz, Especially things like references to temporaries. The only compiler extension I really like using is `#pragma comment` for libraries in my everyday programs that I can't use GCC for, but other compilers should be ignoring that anyway.

Comment: @m00nbeam360, Yeah, empty projects are nicest from my experiences. In fact, I have a template set up that's just an empty console application with a blank source file in it. The real thing is to make sure that "use precompiled headers" is unchecked, or if it is checked, that no code is before the inclusion of it.

Comment: Excellent, thanks so much, chris, Kaz, and bapu sethi! :)

Comment: For teaching high school kids, using Windows, I'd get [MingW](http://www.mingw.org/) (Minimalist GNU for Windows) and a text editor. Exercises would be compiled using a simple command from the shell.  The Visual Studio IDE is complicated and distracting.

Comment: I would have totally gone for that, but guess I'm stuck with VS :( but thanks for the tip anyway!

Comment: @Kaz, CodeBlocks works extremely well for that, too, and is great because it doesn't need projects for all of those single-file programs. I think everyone should have to compile and link at least a couple things from the command line sometime, though. It's a good way to differentiate compiling from linking and learn a good part of what IDE projects do for you. Running from the command line is also a great tool for the explanation of the whole `system("pause")` area, if you choose to touch on that at all.

Comment: Leave it out.  Just make sure you also disable the precompiled-header options in the VC-project so it won't bite you in the back (or do new>project>...>empty project).   A basic project cpp file should start with #include <stdio.h> or maybe #include <iostream.h>.

Comment: @Shimodax, Definitely not `<iostream.h>`. That's not a standard header.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Ya, the basic gist, #include<iostream> :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would make things more complicated for them and that they would learn less.
When you look at cplusplus.com they never use it.
They just need to understand that #include is made to access other libraries.
Including them one by one will teach them what each of them does.
Open for debate of cours :-)

Comment: As proven from above, of course :) but I totally agree with you! Since you answered first, you get this one. Thanks!